# Is it possible to use a github branch in conan package manager?

Tags: git, conan, imgui

I would like to use imguis docking branch. The problem I am trying to figure out is using conan package manager is it possible to ask for a specific branch or would I need to write a custom script to target a specific branch from a package? I am able to get the main imgui package but have not found anything on targeting branches.

I am using cmake and conanfile.txt currently.

This is currently my `conanfile.txt`

```
[requires]
imgui/1.76
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conan recipes (`conanfile.py`) can be implemented to fetch any branch, commit, tag, or download a .zip archive. What it is not possible is to make an arbitrary recipe, implemented by others to do a different thing that it does, because it is defeating the whole purpose of versioning and reproducibility.

When `imgui/1.76` is in a `conanfile` (either .txt or .py), it is fetching the imgui package existing in [ConanCenter](https://conan.io/center/), details in the [imgui package](https://conan.io/center/imgui/1.77) and the full recipe can be found in the [conan-center-index](https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/blob/master/recipes/imgui/all/conanfile.py) github repo, the repo that is used to build all packages in ConanCenter

In that recipe, the `sources()` method is implemented as:

```
def source(self):
   tools.get(**self.conan_data["sources"][self.version])
   extracted_dir = self.name + "-" + self.version
   os.rename(extracted_dir, self._source_subfolder)
```

The `conan_data` attribute is the data from the [conandata.yml file](https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/blob/master/recipes/imgui/all/conandata.yml)

```
sources:
  "1.74":
    url: "https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/archive/v1.74.tar.gz"
    sha256: "2f5f2b789edb00260aa71f03189da5f21cf4b5617c4fbba709e9fbcfc76a2f1e"
  "1.75":
    url: "https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/archive/v1.75.tar.gz"
    sha256: "1023227fae4cf9c8032f56afcaea8902e9bfaad6d9094d6e48fb8f3903c7b866"
  "1.76":
    url: "https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/archive/v1.76.tar.gz"
    sha256: "e482dda81330d38c87bd81597cacaa89f05e20ed2c4c4a93a64322e97565f6dc"
  "1.77":
    url: "https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/archive/v1.77.tar.gz"
    sha256: "c0dae830025d4a1a169df97409709f40d9dfa19f8fc96b550052224cbb238fa8"
```

The sources used for the recipe are the releases corresponding to the version, and when you are using the packages, that cannot be changed.

What is possible is to copy/fork the recipe, adapt it to the needs, like changing the `source()` method, or changing the `conandata.yml` file, to create packages for the specific commits, tags or branches (it would probably be recommended to change the `version`, to differentiate the package from the official release version). It is also recommended to create packages under `username/channel` like `imgui/version@myteam/stable`, to differentiate it from the ConanCenter one. Artifactory CE is completely free too and can be used to host your own packages privately.